# Autopep8 not appearing in Command Palette in VS Code despite being installed and accessible in the terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

In VS Code, I have installed autopep8 and verified that the path is correct. I can use autopep8 in the terminal without any issues. However, when I search for the "python run" item in the Command Palette, I see all the other options from the extension except autopep8.

I have attempted to change the path of autopep8 to use the version installed in my machine's Python installation, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you catch the notes in the VSC plugin?  It details what is expected to be set and how the plugin functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search **Python.Formatting.Provider** in settings and choose autopep8:

[image]

Or you can add the following codes to your settings.json:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8",
```

When you want to use format function, you can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and search **"Format Document"**.

BTW, I suggest you add the following codes to your `settings.json` as well:

```
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
```